# Filling in gaps in data with a merge in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data that looks like this:

```
id t   x 
1  1  3.7 
1  3  1.2 
1  4  2.4 
2  2  6.0 
2  4  6.1 
2  5  6.2
```

For each `id` I want to add observations as necessary so there are values for all 1<=t<=5.

So my desired result is:

```
id t   x 
1  1  3.7 
1  2  .
1  3  1.2 
1  4  2.4 
1  5  .
2  1  .
2  2  6.0 
2  3  .
2  4  6.1 
2  5  6.2
```

My real setting involves massive amounts of data, so I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's probably the simplest way, using the COMPLETETYPES option in PROC SUMMARY.  I'm making the assumption that the combinations of id and t are unique in the data.
The only thing I'm not sure of is whether you'll run into memory issues when running against a very large dataset, I have had problems with PROC SUMMARY in this respect in the past.

```
data have;
input id t x;
cards;
1  1  3.7 
1  3  1.2 
1  4  2.4 
2  2  6.0 
2  4  6.1 
2  5  6.2 
;
run;

proc summary data=have nway completetypes;
class id t;
var x;
output out=want (drop=_:) max=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use PROC EXPAND, if you have ETS.  I'm not sure if it'll do 100% of what you want, but it might be a good start.  It seems like so far the main problem is it won't do records at the start or the end, but I think that's surmountable; just not sure how.

```
proc expand data=have out=want from=daily method=none extrapolate;
by id;
id t;
run;
```

That fills in 2 for id 1 and 3 for id 2, but does not fill in 5 for id 1 or 1 for id 2.

To do it in base SAS, you have a few options.  PROC FREQ with the SPARSE option might be a good option.

```
proc freq data=have noprint;
tables id*t/sparse out=want2(keep=id t);
run;

data want_fin;
merge have want2;
by id t;
run;
```

You could also do this via PROC SQL, with a join to a table with the possible t values, but that seems slower to me (even though the FREQ method requires two passes, FREQ will be pretty fast and the merge is using already sorted data so that's also not too slow).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, provided that you already know the minimum/maximum values for T.  It creates a template that contains all values of ID and T, then merges with the original data set so that you keep the values of X.

```
proc sort data=original_dataset out=template(keep=id) nodupkey;
   by id;
run;

data template;
   set template;
   do t = 1 to 5; /* you could make these macro variables */
      output;
   end;
run;

proc sort data=original_dataset;
   by id t;
run;

data complete_dataset;
   merge template(in=in_template) original_dataset(in=in_original);
   by id t;
   if in_template then output;
run;
```